# Common Properties for all Hibernate hbm files?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4.02.
What i want to do is I want to include some common Hbm mapping to all my hbm files.
e.g Account,Contact hbm.xml files have there own files Id,Name etc.
What i want to do is add some common properites like ModifiedBy and CreatedBy to all these hbm files.

Comment: If you are OK with using annotations, `@MappedSuperclass` is used for this purpose, not sure if it is supported when using `hbm.xml` files.

Comment: No can't use with annotations.

Comment: Is there any way with hbm

Comment: If you have your fields like modifiedBy and createdBy in some kind of abstract class then you probably want to use inheritance in your hbm files. Hibernate provide 3 types of inheritance. For you the best would be "Table per concrete class".

Answer (score 1):

You can define external entities for your xml files. This is not a hibernate specific feature but an xml one. [Check this](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-external-ent).

You can specify a common `.hbm` file with the common properties and then import that in all of your other hbm files.

For example, you can create a file named `commonProperties.hbm` in your classpath with the following content

```
<property name="created" type="timestamp" not-null="true" />
<property name="lastUpdated" type="timestamp" not-null="true"/>
```

And then in your other hbm file, for example in `Person.hbm.xml` you can import the above hbm file as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"
  [<!ENTITY commonProperties SYSTEM "classpath://path/to/commonProperties.hbm">]
  >

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.example.Person" table="person">
....
<id name="id" column="personid">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>

&commonProperties;

<property name="name" column="name" not-null="true" unique="true" length="230" />
....
....
....
```

Hope this helps.